# Removing lines from a live-graph

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, tkinter

I created a gui that can toggle live data on or off. Whhen I toggle the data on the info shows up exactly as expected but when I try and turn it off the generated data remains present and doesn't disappear like I am expecting. My code is as follows, any help is greatly appreciated!

```
if clap1.get()==1:
    data1 = pd.read_csv('test1.csv')
    x1=data1['x_value']
    y1=data1['total_1']

    global line1
    #xlim_low, xlim_high = sensor_graph.get_xlim()
    #ylim_low, ylim_high = sensor_graph.get_ylim()

    if x1.max() > 20000:
        xlim_low = x1.max()-20000
    else:
        xlim_low, xlim_high = sensor_graph.get_xlim()

    sensor_graph.set_xlim(xlim_low, (x1.max() + 5))

    line1, = sensor_graph.plot(x1, y1, label="Test 1", color='black')
    checks[0] = 1
elif  clap1.get()==0 and checks[0]==1:
    sensor_graph.lines.remove(line1)
    checks[0] = 0
```

I think it's of note that for static data, this is able to properly remove the data, the problem became present when I attempted for live data.

**Update**

Ok so I ended up going with a brute-force kind of response that ends up doing what I wanted it to do. Basically, I just clear everything off of the figure then re-initialize the axes, as shown below. If anyone has ideas on how to improve this, please don't hesitate!

```
if clap1.get()==1:
    data1 = pd.read_csv('test1.csv')
    x1=data1['x_value']
    y1=data1['total_1']

    global line1
    xlim_low, xlim_high = sensor_graph.get_xlim()
    #ylim_low, ylim_high = sensor_graph.get_ylim()
    '''
    if x1.max() > 20000:
        xlim_low = x1.max()-20000
    else:
        xlim_low, xlim_high = sensor_graph.get_xlim()
    '''
    sensor_graph.set_xlim(xlim_low, (x1.max() + 5))

    line1, = sensor_graph.plot(x1, y1, label="Test 1", color='orange')
    checks[0] = 1
elif  clap1.get()==0 and checks[0]==1:
    sensor_graph.clear()
    title = "Sensor Pressure Readings"
    sensor_graph.set_title(title)
    sensor_graph.set_xlabel('time (s)')
    checks[0] = 0
```

[The commented code is just to only keep so much information on the screen at any given time]

Comment: How is your `elif` statement getting `line1`? If the first condition fails then `line1` is not defined. Without seeing a working testable example all we can really do is speculate.

Comment: The two variables in the `elif` statement ensured that this wouldn't be the case. The `checks` variable was initialized to 0 and `clap1` wasn't set to 1 until the checkbutton was initialized. I ended up just brute-forcing the conditional to do what I want by clearing the figure then reinitializing the axes but it seems like overkill

Comment: A lot of graph solutions evolve deleting the graph and re adding the graph. As long as you are not updating it constantly you should not see any issues. That said `global line1` should not be in your `if` statement. Place that at the top of your function.

Comment: I had tried that initially and for some reason the code would freak out on me. It would only work when I had it there

Comment: @Mike-SMT also, I am updating it, the `clap1` variable is one of 8 live plots that can be toggled on/off at user will, is there a more appropriate way of doing it?